# Locating file path from a <InMemoryUploadedFile> Django object

Tags: python, django, django-views, filepath, django-file-upload

I have a Django app which, submitting a package, should return values that are inside it..
Submitted the form to a view called "insert":

```
request.FILES['file']
```

returns the file objects, but it is of kind < InMemoryUploadedFile>.
What i need is a way to get the absolute path of the uploaded file, so that i can feed it to a method that will return the values needed

Anyone know how i can accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Surely the name "InMemory" is a clue that the file exists in memory only, so doesn't have a path?

Comment: isn't there a way i can access the file although it's in memory?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You have the file object already.

Comment: url = settings.MEDIA_URL + < upload_to > + request.FILES['file'].name
replace 'upload_to'  with absolute path define in models.py.

Answer (score 1):

Daniel Roseman is correct for the context. But if you already created/inserted the object into the database using `.create(...)` or `obj.save()`. The path of the image can be retrieved by using `obj.<field_name>.name`.
Example:

Suppose you have a model with an image field.

```
my_image = models.ImageFiled(upload_to='my_upload_dir')
```

so,

```
obj = ImageModel.objects.create(image=request.FILES['image']) # let's insert it to db
image_path = obj.image.name

# will return 
'my_upload_dir/myimagename.jpg'
```